# Wordpress don't recognize url parameters

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, url, parameters

I'm using wordpress and developed an angular code to open a button in my DOM The calculated fields are correctly working, but I need to use a angular created code to display a button in according to an parameter (called campanha) value.
Let me try explain th history:
I'm working with Marketing in Google Adwords campaigns, and we created 3  campaigns, (one for Brazil, other for US and other for UK, i.e.), and the values of each campaign are sent to me through the Google search page.

Below I have an example from what I'm talking:

```
<http://www.redecidada.org.br/calculo-cota-aprendizes> (working)
<http://www.redecidada.org.br/calculo-cota-aprendizes?campanha=mg> (404)
<http://www.redecidada.org.br/calculo-cota-aprendizes/?campanha=mg> (404)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is on your wordpress page/configuration.
If you try: http://www.redecidada.org.br/calculo-cota-aprendizes/?nome-campanha=mg.

> There's no problem if you change "campanha" text... The error is in your code/page. Need more info.

Comment: Well, when I run the page in local html file, I can get all resources I developed, but, when I pass the code to Wordpress, the resources are lost.